# OSX 10.5 Finder friendly WebDAV server for linux?

Tags: mac-osx, webdav

Does any know (with authority) of a OSX 10.5 Finder-friendly WebDAV server?

I setup *lighttpd* with the *mod_webdav* on my Ubuntu 9.04 box, but PUTs are not working.  I'd rather not rotate through all the various options...

Answer (score 3):

The OS X finder uses a very large range of webdav features, including the only example of chunked PUTs. The only server i've found that works well is [Apache mod_dav](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html). We use it heavily against Leopard and Maven.

Assid from lighttpd there is also a webdav module for nginx, but it doesn't work at all for properties, and can't do chunked PUTs.

[Apple have also released their calender server](http://trac.calendarserver.org/), which uses CalDAV extentions, so it should work against the finder. I haven't used that product, so can't vouch for it as a general webdav server.

When looking for compatible options you should check out the following projects

- [litmus webdav compliance suite](http://www.webdav.org/neon/litmus/) which will need to pass for the OS X finder to work against it.
- [Prestan webdav benchmark](http://freshmeat.net/projects/prestan/) is also a useful, but not a throughout test.

Answer (score 0):

Just today was I tracking down problem with Mac uploads. Turned out that Mac not only uses chunked encoding when doing PUT (all other clients I checked send Content-Length instead), but it also specifies "Transfer-Encoding: Chunked" with capital C, instead of "chunked", and [mod_proxy doesn't like that](http://www.atnan.com/2008/10/16/memory-issues-with-nsmutableurlrequest-s-sethttpbody-method-in-iphoneos-2-1).

Seems that lighthttpd also doesn't [like chunked transfer encodings](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/619) on PUTs.

We use Tomcat + Apache Jackrabbit Webdav library on server side, and Mac Finder works fine with it.

Comment: Even though rfc2616 defines a single transfer-coding value, "chunked". The following line states that "All transfer coding values are case-insensitive", http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.